# ImportError db_scripts: No module named db_scripts

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I am trying to run Class2go project from Stanford, but as the project is a little bit old I received many errors. I solved most of them but the following error made me crazy. I will be most grateful if you help me. Also I am working on Ubuntu 14.04.

note: I get this error on Manage.py syncdb

Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError db_scripts: No module named db_scripts
```

Comment: too less information to help. did you install everything that is in requirements.txt ?

Comment: Yeah, I did install all of packages in the requirements.txt

Comment: What were you doing when you got this error?

Comment: I guess `runserver`? @NimaSoheily

Comment: I get this error when I run manage.py commands

Comment: The application is trying to import a db_scripts, check if db_scripts.py exists and also within that folder make sure there is __init__.py as well

Comment: I solved the problem myself.